# Rename "floatname" of algorithm2e in beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithm2e

How can I rename the "floatname" of an algorithm designed by `algorithm2e` in `beamer`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
%\floatname{algorithm}{changeThis}
\caption{title}
do something\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name of an algorithm, `algorithm2e` provides the command `\SetAlgorithmName` which allows you to adjust the name displayed in the caption, in references and in an optional list of algorithms.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlgorithmName{algorithmname}{algorithmautorefname}{list of algorithms name}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{title}
do something\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```